# Joomla module position showing

Tags: joomla, module

I want to load a Joomla module in a specific position in a category, but I don't want to show it in an article page on that category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making the assumption that you mean you are using the "Category Blog" or "Category List" feature, and wish a module to appear in the category listings view, but not the article view.

If this is for a single page then you can just set up a menu item for the problematic article using the "single article" menu item type.  The listings will then redirect to that page instead of dynamically generating them.  You can assign modules to individual menu items as normal.

If this is for every article, then one way to do this is to edit the module.

It will have a file called something like mod_yourmodule/mod_yourmodule.php
This will contain code like this

```
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_yourmodule',$params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

Change this to

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$view = $input->get('view');
if ($view != "article") {
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_yourmodule',$params->get('layout', 'default'));
}
```

This will then not render if you are on an article page.  If this file is a core file, you are probably better adding similar code on your template, but using it to add a style sheet which hides the module.  You should never change core files.